# YOLO OpenCV Python cannot show video from RTSP

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp, yolo

I test openCV with Yolo it have no problem when use webcam. I try to use video from RTSP with this code.

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3_training_last.weights', 'yolov3_testing.cfg'
classes = []

with open("classes.txt", "r") as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.10.9:554')

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(100, 3))

while(True):
    _, img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape

    
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
   
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)
    
    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []
    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

when I run this code it show only one image then it freeze. when I comment at line `layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)` the program will not freeze. How to fix it?